# How do you add an entry in the context menu list in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm currently developing an addon for firefox that posts data periodically to a server; but I would like to be able to stop posting when needed. Since you can not call functions within an addon from Firebug/Web Console, the next best alternative is to have an entry 'Stop Posting' in the context menu of the document. Do you know how to add this entry to the list and fire a function when clicked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Modifying_the_context_menu